# Splitting lines from text box and displaying them on a drop down menu W/ Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<div id="dropDown" class="dropdown">
    <button v-on:click.prevent="showDropDown = !showDropDown" class="button dropdown-trigger">
        <div>Keywords</div>
    </button>
    <div v-if="showDropDown">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(key, index) in skags">
                <a href="#">{{key.keyword}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

This is how I've got my dropdown menu and it's pulling keywords from an array of objects where each object should have each line of input from a user. A user's input is within `textarea` and I want to be able to take each line of input and place it within an object. I'm not sure how to identify line breaks and then splitting that up to push them individually. Essentially, there's a box for a user to type in where they are told to break up input by hitting enter to start new line and I want each line of input to be `li` element in a drop-down menu. Any input would be great!

Comment: could you share your script code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `v-model` on your textarea and then `.split('\n')` to create an array from each line:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      content: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      const items = this.content.split('\n')
      return this.content !== '' && !!items.length ? items : []
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.vanilla {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
      <h4>Vanilla JS</h4>
      <hr class="my-3"/>
      <select name="vanilla" class="vanilla">
        <option disabled selected>-- Type in the box below to create options --</option>
        <option v-for="option in items" :value="option">{{ option }}</option>
      </select>
      </v-container>
      <v-container>
        <h4>Vuetify</h4>
        <hr class="my-3"/>
        <v-select :suffix="`${items.length} options`" clearable persistent-hint :items="items" label="Type in the box below to create options" outline></v-select>
        <v-textarea outline name="input-7-4" label="Enter one option per line" v-model="content"></v-textarea>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: So this obviously works but I'm not really sure how this translates into my project without Vuetify? I'll eventually learn it but don't want to get into it without getting Vue JS really down. 

Comment: It's all the same under the hood :). I've added a vanilla example to demonstrate.

Comment: could you replicate that with something like what I've got here, which is how I've got my project set up

https://codepen.io/luis4flames/pen/jXqQZM

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's split function to split text from `\n`

For example

```
var string_from_textarea = `hello
world`;

var array_of_lines = string_from_textarea.split('\n');
```

With above code, you will get an array of lines in `array_of_lines` variable.